# Kendo Angular2 Donut Chart InnerRadius

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-chart, kendo-ui-angular2

From Kendo Angular2's documentation [SeriesItemComponent](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/SeriesItemComponent/)

it is possible to set the innerRadius for a Donut Chart using the visual function. How can I get the instance of the donut chart so that I can invoke this function? I tried treating it as a field and it didn't work.

```
    <kendo-chart-series-item 
        type="donut"
        [data]="pieData"
        field="value"
        categoryField="category"
        [visual.innerRadius]=10>
    </kendo-chart-series-item>
```

Also tried

```
[visual]={ innerRadius: 10 }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `holeSize="10"` instead. It does what you need.

- I have a Kendo Angular2 Slack: https://kendouiangular2.slack.com

Comment: Thanks a lot! Some values for the holeSize seem to have issues. The donut would disappear or it would become a square. But keeping it at 20 worked for me.

Comment: Yeah, i found that. Not sure why but you're welcome. Feel free to join the slack if you want any more help

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Any chance you can send me an invite to your slack channel? email is -  heinrichcoetzee (at) icloud .com